# How to display json values for each <div>s in html page using angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to display json values on my html page on each separate s based on my imageurl value from .json values. Actually I'm facing issues on displaying these values on s, Please help me regarding this how can I iterate and display the values. Thanks in advance.

My desired result may look like (for first iteration):

**html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in newArr>     
    <div data-imgsrc="/images/Image1.nii">     
        <div id="3d0"></div>    
        <div id="sliceX0"></div>    
        <div id="sliceY0"></div>    
        <div id="sliceZ0"></div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

for **second iteration**:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in newArr>     
    <div data-imgsrc="/images/Image2.nii">     
        <div id="3d1"></div>    
        <div id="sliceX1"></div>    
        <div id="sliceY1"></div>    
        <div id="sliceZ1"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I have created it here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/pw0pqg4g/2/)

so that I can apply styles on for each div in my page also.

Comment: you have `$index` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

Use $index in ng-repeat i will give 0,1,2 upto numbers of record

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{item.name}}
{{$index}}
</div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
$scope.items= [{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'c'}]

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Paresh Gami, thank you for your reply, but here i need to display those values as per my image url(data-imgsrc="") , based on this image url(this url varies after each iteration on main div), we can get the values in child(four) divs. It is placed on html view in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given
>   loop variable is set to the current collection item, and $index is set
>   to the item index or key.

HTML code:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="myImage in myImages">
       <img ng-src="{{getImagePath(myImage)}}"/>
          <div id="3d{{$index}}" ng-style="set_color1(myImage )"></div>   
            <div id="sliceX{{$index}}"></div>    
            <div id="sliceY{{$index}}"></div>    
            <div id="sliceZ{{$index}}"></div>  
         </div>
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
 $scope.myImages = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"];

 $scope.getImagePath = function(imageName) {
 return "http://yoursite/location/" + imageName;
 };

$scope.set_color1 = function (myImage) {
return { color: "red" }
}
```

Comment: Hi SVK, thank you for your reply, but here i need to display those values as per my image url(data-imgsrc="") , based on this image url(this url varies after each iteration on main div), we can get the values in child(four) divs.

Comment: Hi SVK, thanks for reply, i have tried this, but i am facing same issue, for me these values are coming from .json file, it is having with name: imageurl and it's value is: /images/Image1 (for first time). Please let me know how to do this ? I've updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pw0pqg4g/3/ , but getting error.

Comment: How can I get imageurl value at <img ng-src="{{   }}"/> from that json values from fiddle, so that we can display the images. Thanks in advance.